# Why regex match object is not matching larger strings?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get all href links from an HTML document through regex, the code is working fine for most of the links but it is unable to get larger links(strings). I don't know why, I've read the documentation but couldn't find anything related. following is the little demo code for the problem demonstration:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=href=)(").*(")')


strings_list = [r'<link href="plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">',
r'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css">',
r'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css">']

for line in strings_list:
    mo = re.search(regex, line)
    print(mo)
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSZ5J.png)

Notice that the first string from the list has not fully captured.

Answer (score 0):

It is fully captured, It's just not printing it completely in the match object

Try "re.search(regex, line).group()":

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(?<=href=)(").*(")')


strings_list = [r'<link href="plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">',
r'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css">',
r'<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css">']

for line in strings_list:
    mo = re.search(regex, line)
    print(mo)
    print(mo.group())
```

[image]